# python receive file from html form

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a form with an input tag and a submit button:

```
<input type="file" name="filename" size="25">
```

I have a python file that handles the post:

```
def post(self):
```

The file that I'm receiving in the form is an .xml file, in the python post function I want to send that 'foo.xml' to another function that is going to validate it (using minixsv)

My question is how do I retrieve the file? I tried:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

inputfile = form.getvalue('filename')
```

but this puts the content in the inputfile, I don't have a 'foo.xml' file per se that I can pass to the minisxv function which request a .xml file not the text...

**Update** I found a function that accepts text instead of an input file, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oftentimes, there's also a function to extract XML from a string. For example, minidom has [`parseString`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parseString), and lxml [`etree.XML`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#XML).

If you have the content, you can make a file-like object with [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
content = form.getvalue('filename')
fileh = StringIO(content)
# You can now call fileh.read, or iterate over it
```

If you must have a file on the disk, use [tempfile.mkstemp](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp):

```
import tempfile
content = form.getvalue('filename')
tmpf, tmpfn = tempfile.mkstemp()
tmpf.write(content)
tmpf.close()
# Now, give tmpfn to the function expecting a filename

os.unlink(tmpfn) # Finally, delete the file
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be the best answer, but why not consider using [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/io.html#io.StringIO) on your `inputfile` variable, and passing the StringIO object as the file handle to your minisxv function? Alternately, why not open an actual new file handle for `foo.xml`, save the contents of inputfile to it (i.e., via `open`), and then pass `foo.xml` to your minisxv function?